# Rails validation only if input matches a string from a dynamic array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, autocomplete, mongoid

I have a form that accepts inputs for the Bill model. The form has an autocomplete that gives you words from an dynamic array that is created in the Transactions model. I want to make a validation that only allows words from the array to be allowed as inputs. I found the validation validates_inclusion_of but I am unsure if this is the right validation and how to link the validation in the model to check the array that is created for the autocomplete.

The route in my Transactions controller is autocomplete_names

How can I make the validation check the input against the route in my Transactions controller.

Here is the validation I have so far or am I using this in the wrong context and need to make a custom validation?

```
validates_inclusion_of :my_bill, in: [Transaction::autocomplete_names], :allow_blank => true, message: "Bill name not found in your account, please try again"
```

This is wrong and not working so I need to figure out what to put in the ":in" for this validation

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I am using Rails 4.0.10

Comment: When you enter `Transaction::autocomplete_names` in your Rails Console, what is the output?

Comment: That is wrong, autocomplete_names is an action in my Transaction controller. I need it to look for a substring within an array of strings. So for example my_bill could be "directv" and it would look thru my Transaction model trans_name field which is an array of strings and check if their are any sub-strings that match that input. I use the controller action to call my autocomplete on the array and thought I could use the same action on the validation. But I may be wrong.

Comment: In your validation, the `Transaction::autocomplete_names` command is looking for a function in your `Transaction` model. You could write a function in your model that outputs an array from your database column `:trans_name`.

Comment: So I am trying to figure out what to check against in the validation, an action? or a method? and how exactly to call that in the validation. I figured the action would be right because it is what I used to find the substring to do the autocomplete

Comment: I've updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You could write the following in your Transaction model:

```
def self.autocompete_names
    Transaction.all.pluck(:trans_name)
end
```

Then in your Bill model, you could use the following validation:

```
validates :my_bill, inclusion: { in:          Transaction.autocomplete_names,
                                 allow_blank: true,
                                 message:     "Bill name not found in your account, please try again" }
```

Since you're using Rails 4, I believe the above structure for validations is more up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class method in `Transaction` which will return the array of names. And then call this method in `validates_inclusion_of`.

Add a class method which should look something like

```
def self.autocomplete_names
  # return an array of words matching bills associated with the user's account
end
```

And then make use of it in the validation.

```
validates_inclusion_of :my_bill, in: Transaction.autocomplete_names
```

From the documentation,

> The :allow_blank option is similar to the :allow_nil option. This option will let validation pass if the attribute's value is blank?, like nil or an empty string for example.

Remove the `allow_blank` option from the validation. Your validation should look like

```
validates_inclusion_of :my_bill, in: Transaction.autocomplete_names, message: "Bill name not found in your account, please try again"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a controller action for a validation. Controller actions are for manipulating data and giving the response back. They are different from methods defined in your models.

Here you need a method inside your `Transaction` class that will return the array of strings on which you want to validate inclusion of `my_bill`. Something like this:

```
class Transaction
  def self.autocomplete_names
    # return that array of strings
  end
end
```

and inside `Bill` you need to modify your validation as:

```
class Bill
  validates_inclusion_of :my_bill,
                         in: -> { Transaction::autocomplete_names },
                         allow_blank: true,
                         message: "Bill name not found in your account, please try again"
end
```

Please note the use of lambda `->` inside validation. If you don't use it, the array of strings will be evaluated at the time of class definition only. But you want actual data from database everytime you run this validation. So, it should be a lambda, i guess. Not sure about the syntax. Please give it a try.

You can also drop `allow_blank` part if you don't want blank values to be stored in database for `my_bill`.